# How to shield Math. characters ">" or "<" when you use TextFlowUtil.importFromString?

Tags: actionscript-3, flex4

I have a `TextArea` named `TextView`. The following is my code:

```
TextView.textFlow = TextFlowUtil.importFromString("if (i < 36)");
```

when trying to implement this line of code, I get the error:

> [Fault] exception, information = TypeError: Error # 1090:

How can I fix this? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Encode them as entities:

```
<   =   &lt;
>   =   &gt;
```

Per your example, would become:

```
TextView.textFlow = TextFlowUtil.importFromString("if (i &lt; 36)");
```